# Woocommerce product loop display, products and categories headache

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Been trying to solve an issue I am facing, and I am stuck. I modified a lot of woocommerce default behavior thanks to this community myself, but it seem I cannot find any poiner how to cope with this one...

My problem is that I am displaying only categories on a shop page, and of course list products inside them. Some products do have subcategories I would like (I would have) to display after all products in certain category. Now subs are shown as first item, products after. If I remove the maybe_show_categories filter from the woocommerce_product_loop_start and echo it in arhive-product, than I lose all categories on the shop page (it shows products instead, regardles of the display type set to categories only).

Is there a way to make a conditional remove filter to affect only the current product category and remove subcategory from the loop so I could echo it back before the loop end, but that it does not affect other categories, only subs? Something like if it's a child? Or is there a way to modify the loop it self to list subcategories only after the products?

Many thanks for Your help!

**EDIT:**

So, I tried:

```
if ( is_product_category() ) {
echo woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories ( ' ' );
}
```

This part works and it echoes subcategory after products in their respective category. However, this duplicates the subcategory and I cannot seem to find the way to get rid of it's first instance which is displayed before products.

I tried

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 
'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );
```

But it removes all categories, not just subs, and none of conditional wraps I could think of helps with this.

Hope it's enough to clarify the problem I'm having...

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to come with a "solution" in lack of the better one. Still hope someone will post an real one, but for now I managed with hiding first-child:

```
.tax-product_cat div.some-element-wrapper:first-child {
 display: none;
}
```

So in lack of a better solution for now, I hide the first child (in case of more subcategories I'll have to hide them as well), and then I echo them before product loop end. Seems to work.

**EDIT 3:**

Actually it's not working as it's hiding also the first child in subcategory, which is not something I would call usable. Instead I have to use category term selector in css for every category listing where us subcategory to hide / reposition, so it's actually not usable for somebody who has more than few to reposition... 
Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You can help others help you by providing code examples that clearly illustrate what you have already tried and where you got stuck. This greatly increases the chance of a user being able to solve your particular problem.

Comment: Dear MBS, thanks. I edited OP.